# Python, tk: How do I prevent the execfile from running automatically?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

So I'm trying to make a main menu. But my code automatically runs *execfile("list.py")* before making the button for it.

```
def list():
    master.withdraw()
    execfile("list.py")

listb = Button(master, text = "Patient List", command=list())
listb.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Try removing the parentheses from `command=list()`.

Comment: also probably better not use list as a function name

Comment: Also probably better to `import` a Python file than `execfile` it.